# Invalid Length Parameter Passed to The Left or SUBSTRING funcction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an `addrLines` field formatted like `[Address] [City], [State] [Zip]`, and another field with just the `[city]` data, I am trying to extract just the `[Address]` portion from the `addrLines` field. but this query returns invalid length parameter error.

```
SELECT LEFT(addrLines,(CHARINDEX(',',addrLines)-LEN(city))) 
FROM MyTable
```

Could anyone suggest what I am doing incorrectly?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely means that you have an entry in `addrLines` that doesn't have a comma in it or `LEN(city)` is greater than `CHARINDEX(',',addrLines)`.  In either one of those cases, you're likely going to get a negative number back for `CHARINDEX(',',addrLines)-LEN(city)`, which the `LEFT` function can't use.

Comment: This is absolutely the issue... back to the drawing board on how to extract the address string

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(addrLines,(CHARINDEX(',',addrLines + ',')-LEN(city))) 
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
SELECT LEFT(addrLines,(CHARINDEX(city + ',',addrLines)-1)) 
FROM MyTable
```